# How to do proper join?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Hello I have several table for dashboard, user, user_dahboard, user_organisation. Below are table schema.

dashboard_user

```
id   user_id    dashboard_id
1       2         1
2       1         1
3       4         2
4       1         2
```

org_user

```
id   user_id    org_id
1      1         1
2      2         1
3      3         2
4      4         2
```

dashboard

```
id  dashboard_title
1   World's Bank Data
2   Births
3   Unicode Test
```

Now I want to fetch all the dashboard from same organisation user. Like user id 1 can see the all the dashboard which developed by same organisation user.  I did following query for the same

```
SELECT 
    dashboards.id AS dashboards_id 
FROM 
    dashboards 
    JOIN dashboard_user AS dashboard_user_1 ON dashboards.id = dashboard_user_1.dashboard_id 
        JOIN organization_user AS organization_user_1 ON organization.id = organization_user_1.org_id 
    JOIN ab_user ON ab_user.id = dashboard_user_1.user_id 
WHERE ab_user.id = 1
```

Expected result like for where condition usr_id=1 it should return all the dashboard_id which belong user who having same organisation as user1.

result

```
user    org      dashboard
1        1        1
2        1        2
```

Comment: What did you get as result ? Moreover Why did you tag with two DBMS?

Comment: I expect filter the dashboard  for the user who belong from same organisation. Like if  I put where user = 1 than it should give all the dashboard who belong from same organisation user.

Comment: can you share expected sample results within the question please?

Comment: What does this mean "can see the all the dashboard which developed by same organisation user"?

Comment: Your results are wrong, how to expect the dashboards created by users who belongs to the same organisations, and the `org` column has 2 different value!

Comment: @MAZux Thanks. I update the result.

Comment: Why is it dashboard=2 for user=2 in the expected result?

Comment: @forpas Yes something wrong with data. I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that any `JOIN` is necessary.  If you just want the dashboards for a given user:

```
SELECT du.dashboards_id 
FROM dashboard_user du
WHERE du.user_id = 1;
```

If you want all dashboards from the same organization as `user_id = 1`, then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT du.dashboards_id 
FROM dashboard_user du
WHERE du.user_id IN (SELECT ou.user_id
                     FROM org_user ou JOIN
                          org_user ou1
                          ON ou.org_id = ou1.org_id
                     WHERE ou1.user_id = 1
                    );
```

Or, as a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT du.dashboards_id 
FROM dashboard_user du JOIN
     org_user ou
     ON du.user_id = ou.user_id JOIN
     org_user ou1
     ON ou1.org_id = ou.ord_id AND
        ou1.user_id = 1
```